# Create-or-Err with Objectify

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I'm getting started with Google App Engine, and I'm using Objectify.  How do I create a root entity in the data store, but err if it already exists?  I didn't find anything built in for this (e.g. `DatastoreService.put()` and therefore `ofy().save()` will overwrite an existing entity instead of err).  The simple technique I am used to is to do this in a transaction:

1. Err if already exists
2. Save

However, that is not idempotent; it would err in step 1 if the transaction executes twice.  Here is the best I've come up with so far, *not* in a transaction:

1. Err if already exists
2. Save
3. Fetch
4. Err if it's not the data we just created

Or, if I don't mind two requests to save the *same* data both succeeding, I can skip the initial lookup:

1. Fetch
2. Report success if it's the same data we are about to create
3. Err if already exists, but is not the same data we are about to create
4. Save

That is doable, but it gets a little bulky to accomplish what I thought would be a very simple operation.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should guarantee consistent behavior:

```
final String id = // pick the unique id
final long txnId = // pick a uuid, timestamp, or even just a random number

ofy().transact(new VoidWork() {
    public void vrun() {
        Thing th = ofy().load().type(thing.class).id(id).now();
        if (th != null) {
            if (th.getTxnId() == txnId)
                return;
            else
                throw ThingAlreadyExistsException();
        }

        th = createThing(id, txnId);
        ofy().save().entity(th);
    }
});
```

Comment: Can't this throw `ThingAlreadyExistsException` when it did not actually already exist?  In the case that the GAE transaction throws an exception, but it was "committed and eventually will be applied successfully", I got the impression that Objectify will re-run that transaction.  Then, I thought, it would see the results of the first transaction and throw the exception.

Comment: I don't think so.  Objectify only retries when it encounters a ConcurrentModificationException, and I don't think that in that scenario the save would ever be "committed and eventually applied successfully".

Comment: From [the docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions#Java_Using_transactions): "You can receive `DatastoreTimeoutException`, `ConcurrentModificationException`, or `DatastoreFailureException` exceptions in cases where transactions have been committed and eventually will be applied successfully."

Comment: Good point. I have updated the answer to address a CME on successful commit. I wish Google would elaborate on the circumstances that can produce this situation.

Comment: @stickfigure Genius!  Thanks for the edit - now I'm convinced.  :)  That is much easier than verifying all the data I wrote is the same.

Comment: @stickfigure I just found the perfect, fail-proof `txnId` to use.  `DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService().allocateIds(Key.create(this).getRaw(), "Transaction Key", 1).getStart()` ([docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/KeyRange)).  Thought you might be interested, and that you may want to update your answer if anyone in the future is interested.