# Some properties of an Entity need full-text search, others don't

Tags: java, google-app-engine, full-text-search, objectify

In my app I have an entity called `Product` that holds the details of the
product listings to be shown on the site.  Since the name (title) and
description of the product need to be full-text searchable, I am putting them in
a separate `Document` (as defined by Google's App Engine **[Search API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/)**).  All other
properties remain in the `Product` entity, which is stored as per usual in the
**Google Datastore** using **Objectify**.

A slug created from the `name` property of the `Product` is the `doc_id` of the
`Document`.  This same slug is the (`String`) ID of an entity (let's call it
`ProductLookup`) that I will use to get the `Key` to the corresponding/matching
`Product`.

**NOTE:** The `Product` has an auto-generated `Long` id as the `name` property
(and therefore the slug used to lookup a `Product`) can change even after the
creation of the `Product` — this way I just create a new `ProductLookup`
entity when `name` changes.

Since I am splitting the information that would normally be in a single entity
into two different objects (the `Product` and the `Document`, not to mention the
extra `ProductLookup` entity), are there any special cases I should be watching
out for?  Any suggestions?

---

If I have a reference to a `Product`, I can use the slug to get the correspoding
`Document`.

If I have a slug, I can use `ProductLookup` to get a `Product` and use the slug
as the `doc_id` of the `Document`.

If I find a set of `Document`s via Search API, I can use their `doc_id`s to get
the `ProductLookup`, then the `Product`.

Comment: I have since updated the design to have all data in the datastore entity, and create Documents in the Search API with the full-text searchable fields. This leads to some duplication, but a lot less hassle.

Answer (score 1):

My current project has a similar situation.  Originally I was using a technique like yours, and the only caveat I know of is the extra care you have to take to ensure adding and deleting products from the two sources always succeed or fail together.  Datastore operations can be put in a transaction, but Search API operations will not obey the rules of that transaction.  For example, if you delete from both the datastore and the search api within a transaction, and that transaction fails, the product will not be deleted from the datastore, but it may still be deleted from the search api.  To ensure they stay synchronized, use a technique like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22362192), and be sure your search api operations are last within your transactions.

I have since amended my approach to save the entire object within the datastore, and also store a copy of the searchable fields in the search api.  The drawback to this approach is that you pay for the additional storage.  The benefit is that when you aren't searching, retrievals are cheaper.  This is especially true when Objectify finds your objects in memcache.

To support my approach, I wrote my own "mini-objectify" that persists objects to the search API.  It has its own version of `@Igore`, so I can use the same POJO for both, and only persist the fields I choose to the search api.

Comment: Since asking that question (and getting no responses :-) I too have shifted to a design similar to yours -- duplicate some data in the Search API (see my comment on the original question), though I have no plans to implement a mini-objectify (yet ;-).

Comment: @markvgti Ha!  I should have read the comment.  It would have saved me some typing.  :)

Comment: @markvgti However, it is still important to use transactions well to keep the two in sync.  That is to say, my first paragraph still applies.

Comment: Not your fault at all: I added the comment after reading your comment, as I realized others might come along and will have no way of knowing that I've changed my design :-).

Comment: Yes, you are right. I haven't implemented the Search API yet, but here's what I am thinking: it's not so bad if an Entity has been created but not yet indexed (a task can search for such entities & fix the situation). It's also not super-bad if an entity has been deleted but the corresponding Search API index failed to clean up: once again it can be handled by a periodic task. Yes, users will get invalid entries in their results, but that's not catastrophic.